# In FORTRAN, what happens if I call a variable that has been allocated, but unchanged after allocation?

Tags: fortran

Example here:

```
integer, allocatable , dimension(:) :: dates, datesecs

!
! open file and get fileid
!
if (masterproc) then 
   call getfil( fname, filen, 0 )
   call wrap_open( filen, 0, fileid )
   write(6,*)'open_met_datafile: ',trim(filen)
endif

call get_dimension( fileid, 'time', timesize )

if ( associated(times) ) deallocate(times)
allocate( times(timesize) )

if (masterproc) then

   allocate( dates(timesize) )
   allocate( datesecs(timesize) )

   call wrap_inq_varid( fileid, 'date',    dateid  )
   call wrap_inq_varid( fileid, 'datesec', secid  )

   call wrap_get_var_int( fileid, dateid, dates )
   call wrap_get_var_int( fileid, secid,  datesecs  )

   do i=1,timesize
      year = dates(i) / 10000
      month = mod(dates(i),10000)/100
      day = mod(dates(i),100)
      times(i) = get_time_float( year, month, day, datesecs(i) )
   enddo

   deallocate( dates )
   deallocate( datesecs )       

endif ! masterproc
```

The code is actually in "  subroutine open_met_datafile( grid, fname, fileid, times, check_dims )" - at http://www.cesm.ucar.edu/models/cesm1.0/cesm/cesmBbrowser/html_code/cam/metdata.F90.html

I ran a PowerGREP on the code, and it appears that the "dates" array wasn't assigned anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about what will happen if you do the sequence allocate (var), var=value, deallocate (var), then use the value of "var"?   If that is your question, this is illegal and undefined.  Even if it appears that your source code doesn't change "var" after it is deallocated, that variable is undefined after you deallocate it.   Fortran might reuse that memory for a different purpose so if you access that variable you could obtain any value.   You either need to keep track of whether a variable is allocated or use the associated intrinsic to find out.

Edit: As @walklyk wrote, it depends on what is in subroutine wrap_get_var_int.  There are many cases.  They are well explained in "The Fortran 2003 Handbook" by Adams et al.  (You can find this info on google books by searching for "allocatable argument".)  If the dummy argument doesn't have the allocatable attribute then things are obvious ... the subroutine can change the value (unless the intent is "in"), which you say it doesn't.   If the dummy has the allocatable attribute, there are several cases.  If the "intent" is "out", then the variable is automatically deallocated upon entry!   If the intent is out or inout, the procedure can explicitly change the allocation status.

Comment: Oops - sorry - I messed up the title. I'm talking about what happens after I allocate first, and then use the variable var.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely up to date with the latest Fortran improvements, but in Fortran-77 such variables would have a persistent value, so the value would not change from call to call unless explicitly assigned.

Comment: Okay, so what would the value of each entry in the "year" array be based on this code alone?

Comment: @InquilineKea:  There is no way for me to tell.  What does `wrap_get_var_int()` do?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you (possible; it's late and I'm quite tired) but F77 did not have allocate. Are you referring to status of variables in procedures between calls to the procedure?

Comment: @Rook:  Yes indeed, I'm referring the scope and persistence of variables in general.  To do dynamic allocation in F77, external modules had to be called.  The most popular was the C runtime library, at least on VMS and iNtel implementations.

Comment: "allocatable" variables were added in Fortran 90 and at least one behavior was changed in Fortran 95.  FORTRAN 77 doesn't tell one anything about how this language feature works.  For example, local allocatable variables of procedures are not persistent ... the are automatically deallocated upon exit from the procedure ... starting with Fortran 95.